# Opening Streamlit websites through Selenium does not render child elements properly

Tags: selenium-webdriver, streamlit

I have this code:

```py
chrome_driver = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
chrome_option = Options()

chrome_option.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_option.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_option.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
chrome_option.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=new_chrome_driver, options=chrome_option)

# Test with https://moyocrawling.streamlit.app/
# <button kind="secondary" data-testid="baseButton-secondary" class="st-emotion-cache-13ejsyy ef3psqc12"><div data-testid="stMarkdownContainer" class="st-emotion-cache-10fz3ls e1nzilvr5"><p>Just Moyos</p></div></button>
# <button kind="secondary" data-testid="baseButton-secondary" class="st-emotion-cache-13ejsyy ef3psqc12"><div data-testid="stMarkdownContainer" class="st-emotion-cache-10fz3ls e1nzilvr5"><p>Just Moyos</p></div></button>
# xpath: /html/body/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/section[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div/button
try:
    driver.get("https://moyocrawling.streamlit.app/")
except:
    driver.quit()
    sys.exit()

def print_elements(elements, prefix=''):
    for element in elements:
        print(f"{prefix}Tag: {element.tag_name}, Class: {element.get_attribute('class')}")
        if element.tag_name == 'button':
            print(f"{prefix}Found a button: {element.get_attribute('outerHTML')}")
        elif element.tag_name == 'a':
            print(f"{prefix}Found a link: {element.get_attribute('outerHTML')}")
        elif element.tag_name == 'div':
            print(f"{prefix}Found a div: {element.get_attribute('outerHTML')}")
        elif element.tag_name == 'section':
            print(f"{prefix}Found a section: {element.get_attribute('outerHTML')}")
        children = element.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//*")
        print_elements(children, prefix + '  ')

try:
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    iframes = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe')
    print(f"Found {len(iframes)} iframes.")
    # Optionally, print out attributes of each iframe to help identify the right one
    for index, iframe in enumerate(iframes):
        print(f"Iframe {index}: {iframe.get_attribute('src')}")
        driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
        # Wait until the iframe's document is fully loaded
        WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(lambda d: d.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
        print("Iframe is ready")
        iframe_html = driver.page_source
        print(f"Iframe HTML: {iframe_html}")
        logs = driver.get_log('browser')
        for log in logs:
            print(log)
        
        WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#root:not(:empty)")))
        dynamic_content = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById('root').innerHTML;")
        print(f"Dynamic content: {dynamic_content}")
        driver.switch_to.default_content()
        for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
            print(entry)
except:
    print('iframe not found')
    driver.quit()
    sys.exit()

try:
    # time.sleep(10)
    # Just_moyos_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.st-emotion-cache-13ejsyy.ef3psqc12')
    # Just_moyos_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.st-emotion-cache-13ejsyy.ef3psqc12')))
    #focus on iframe
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframes[0])
    time.sleep(10)
    print(driver.execute_script("return document.location.href;"))
    nested_elements = driver.execute_script("""return document.querySelector('#root').querySelectorAll('*').length;""")
    print(f"Nested elements count: {nested_elements}")
except:
    print('Just Moyos button not clickable')
    driver.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

I ran this code on AWS Instance but my selenium couldn't load further down the Streamlit's iframe. It only loaded the first div (ID=root) under the iframe.

When I take a screenshot, it's like this (completely white):

[image]

My python version at the server machine is 3.6.8 and chromedriver version is 91.0.4472.19.

What could be the possible reason for this error?

I tried webdriverwait for loading the element as well, but it didn't work because when I logged the readystate of the iframe and the div ID = root, it said "complete"

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on using an old version and tried the latest version. It got resolved when I used the latest version regardless of whether I run it on AWS EC2 or my local computer.